# How to pass data in element loop using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input fields in loop and I want to pass the data from an object inside the loop using jquery or Javascript.

The data is coming from `data` variable

Here is my code

```
    success: function(data) {
        // var html = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            obj.createProgress(data[i]["name"], data[i]["path"], data[i]["size"]);
            // html.push('<input type="text" class="form-control mkcInput" name="new_file_name[]" value="' + data[i].file_name + '" placeholder="File Name">');
        }


        $('.ajax-file-upload-progress input').each(function(i, val) {
            // console.log(data);
            $(this).val(i);
        })
        // $.each(data, function(i, val) {

        // })
    }
```

Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help..

```js
var data = [{
    name: "Allahabad Bank",
    id: 0,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    name: "Andhra Bank",
    id: 1,
    selected: true
  },
  {
    name: "Andhra Bank",
    id: 2,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    name: "Andhra Bank",
    id: 3,
    selected: false
  }
];
var html = "";
data.forEach(element => {
  html += "<input value=" + element.name + " ></input>";
});

document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="div">
</div>
```

Comment: This is not working, my input fields render already i just want to pass the data to them

Comment: I got the solution and posted the solution

Answer (score 0):

**Answer Found**

```
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            obj.createProgress(data[i]["name"], data[i]["path"], data[i]["size"]);
        }
        $.each(data, function(i, val) {
            if ($('.ajax-file-upload-progress').children('.mkcInput').length == '') {
                $('.ajax-file-upload-progress').children('.ajax-file-upload-bar').after('<input type="text" class="form-control mkcInput" name="new_file_name[]" value="" placeholder="File Name">');
            } else {}
        });
        $('.ajax-file-upload-progress input').each(function(i) {
            $(this).val(data[i].file_name);
        });
    }
```